# Scaling Image doesn't work properly on phone

Tags: android, kotlin, bitmap, scale

I'm trying to draw a playing card with a design on the back. I have 1 size drawable and scale those drawables programmatically.

It works perfectly on my tablet (Pixel C, running Android 8.1) but the design for the back of the card doesn't scale properly on my phone (Pixel 3a, running Android 10.) On the Pixel 3a, the image is much larger than expected and is not centered on the back of the card. Also, the card itself seems to scale properly, just not the design that's put on top of it.

EDIT: This seems to be an OS level issue. I had an emulated Pixel 3a with API 29 (Android 10, same as my physical phone) which looked the same as the screenshot from my physical phone below. But when I created an emulator of a Pixel 3a with API 27 (Android 8.1) it looks like it does on the tablet running the same OS. Any ideas why?? Seems like it's a bug at the OS level, but I'm not sure what function contains the issue, or how exactly to reproduce it.

EDIT 2: It looks like API 27 is the last one which displays what I would expect to see. I tried emulators with API 28, 29, and R, and all of them show this image much larger than I would expect.

Here is the code I'm running:

```
    private fun createImageInImageCenter(context: Context, backgroundBitmap: Bitmap, bitmapToDrawInTheCenter : Bitmap) : Drawable {

        // Figure out width / height
        val resultBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(
            backgroundBitmap.width,
            backgroundBitmap.height,
            backgroundBitmap.config
        )

        val scaledCenter = scaleImage(bitmapToDrawInTheCenter, backgroundBitmap.height /2,
            backgroundBitmap.width / 2)

        val canvas = Canvas(resultBitmap)
        // Draw background
        canvas.drawBitmap(backgroundBitmap, Matrix(), Paint())
        // Draw design centered on top
        canvas.drawBitmap(
            scaledCenter,
            ((backgroundBitmap.width - scaledCenter.width) / 2).toFloat(), // left
            ((backgroundBitmap.height - scaledCenter.height) / 2).toFloat(), // top
            Paint()
        )

        return BitmapDrawable(context.resources, resultBitmap)
    }

    private fun scaleImage (image: Bitmap, maxHeight: Int, maxWidth: Int = -1) : Bitmap {
        var ratio = 1f

        if(maxWidth > 0 && image.width > maxWidth)
            ratio = maxWidth.toFloat() / image.width

        if(maxHeight > 0 && (image.height * ratio).roundToInt() > maxHeight)
            ratio = maxHeight.toFloat() / image.height

        val sizeX = (image.width * ratio).roundToInt()
        val sizeY = (image.height * ratio).roundToInt()

        return Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(image, sizeX, sizeY, false)
    }

    fun drawCard() {

        // Resize the card itself
        val cardHeight = context.resources.getDimension(R.dimen.card_max_height)
        val back = scaleImage(context.getDrawable(R.drawable.card_black)!!, cardHeight.toInt())

        // Resize the design on the card
        val image = scaleImage(context.getDrawable(R.drawable.triforce)!!, back.height / 2, back.width / 2)

        pic = createImageInImageCenter(context, back, image)
    }
```

This is what it looks like on the tablet: [image: tablet]

vs what it looks like on the phone: [image: phone]

Note: I'm not sure why the images are so large, or how to scale them here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a way to make it work, partly thanks to @mmmcho for his answer, and also thanks to another answer that I found somewhere else with both conversion functions.

```
    fun convertDpToPixel(context: Context, dp: Float): Float {
        return dp * (context.resources
            .displayMetrics.densityDpi.toFloat() / DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_DEFAULT)
    }

    fun convertPixelsToDp(context: Context, px: Float): Float {
        return px / (context.resources
            .displayMetrics.densityDpi.toFloat() / DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_DEFAULT)
    }

    private fun createImageInImageCenter(context: Context, background: Drawable, bitmapToDrawInTheCenter : Drawable) : Drawable {

        val backgroundBitmap = background.toBitmap()
        // Figure out width / height
        val resultBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(
            backgroundBitmap.width,
            backgroundBitmap.height,
            backgroundBitmap.config
        )

        val canvas = Canvas(resultBitmap)

        // Draw background
        canvas.drawBitmap(backgroundBitmap, Matrix(), Paint())

        val scaledCenter = scaleImage(context, bitmapToDrawInTheCenter, resultBitmap.height / 2,
            resultBitmap.width / 2)

        // Do conversion from DP to Pixel for API 28+
        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 28) {
            // Draw design on top
            canvas.drawBitmap(
                scaledCenter,
                (backgroundBitmap.width.toFloat() /2) - convertDpToPixel(context, scaledCenter.width.toFloat() / 2),
                (backgroundBitmap.height.toFloat() /2) - convertDpToPixel(context, scaledCenter.height.toFloat() / 2),
                Paint()
        )
        }
        else {
            // Draw design on top
            canvas.drawBitmap(
                scaledCenter,
                ((backgroundBitmap.width - scaledCenter.width) / 2).toFloat(), // left
                ((backgroundBitmap.height - scaledCenter.height) / 2).toFloat(), // top
                Paint()
            )
        }

        return BitmapDrawable(context.resources, resultBitmap)
    }

    private fun scaleImage (context : Context, image: Bitmap, maxHeight: Int, maxWidth: Int = -1) : Bitmap {
        var ratio = 1f

        // Do conversion from pixels to DP for API 28+
        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 28)
        {
            val width = convertPixelsToDp(context, image.width.toFloat())
            val height = convertPixelsToDp(context, image.height.toFloat())
            val newMaxWidth = convertPixelsToDp(context, maxWidth.toFloat())
            val newMaxHeight = convertPixelsToDp(context, maxHeight.toFloat())

            if(newMaxWidth > 0 && width > newMaxWidth)
                ratio = newMaxWidth / image.width

            if(newMaxHeight > 0 && (height * ratio).roundToInt() > newMaxHeight)
                ratio = newMaxHeight / image.height
        }
        else {
            if (maxWidth > 0 && image.width > maxWidth)
                ratio = maxWidth.toFloat() / image.width

            if (maxHeight > 0 && (image.height * ratio).roundToInt() > maxHeight)
                ratio = maxHeight.toFloat() / image.height
        }

        val sizeX = (image.width * ratio).roundToInt()
        val sizeY = (image.height * ratio).roundToInt()

        return Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(image, sizeX, sizeY, false)
    }

    fun drawCard() {
        val back = context.getDrawable(R.drawable.card_black)!!

        // Image to draw on the back
        val image = context.getDrawable(R.drawable.triforce)!!

        pic = createImageInImageCenter(context, back, image)
    }
```

It took a lot of experimenting to figure out what needed to be converted, and which way it needed to be converted, but I figured it out :-)

Answer (score 1):

What is the unit you used for R.dimen.card_max_height?

Is it dp or px?
This matters because if you used px, it can give you very different results on different screens having different resolutions. 
If you used dp, it's better to use somthing like this

```
int px = Math.round(TypedValue.applyDimension(
    TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 14,r.getDisplayMetrics()));
```

(Sorry for the java version)

You can't just convert it to int without considering the different screen sizes and resolutions.

> And also... I noticed you used
>
> ```
> context.getDrawable(R.drawable.triforce)!!
> ```
>
> I think this is not recommended in Kotlin. It defeats Kotlin
>   supposedly having gotten rid of the *nullpointerexception*, you
>   should check if it doesn't return null and then perform the operation

Comment: Also check the units for back.height and width, if it's all good and plays well with max card height

Comment: `R.dimen.card_max_height` is in dp. I tried converting it to pixels (with code similar to what you provided) and it made no difference.

Comment: As for the null thing, this is currently just proof-of-concept code and is not finalized. That's going to be a variable eventually, and I will check for null on the final product. Right now the hard-coded image is just a placeholder.

Comment: Your answer didn't get me all the way to the solution, but it did help, so I gave you an upvote. Thanks for pushing me in the right direction!